# Proof of a theorem regarding subsequences and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am attempting to understand the following theorem and it's proof as outlined in my textbook for Real Analysis.

**Theorem**: *Let  $(s_n)$ be a sequence. If t is in $\mathbb{R}$, then there is a subsequence of $(s_n)$ converging to t if and only if the set* { $n \in\mathbb{N} \space$ : |${s_n} - t| <\varepsilon$} *is infinite for all* $\varepsilon > 0$.

The forward implication is easy to check. For example if lim$_k$$s_{n_k}$ = $t$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, then all but finitely many of the $n_k$s are in { $n \in\mathbb{N} \space$ : |${s_n} - t| <\varepsilon$}.

**Proof**: First suppose the set { $n \in\mathbb{N} \space$ : $\space s_n = t$} is infinite. Then there are subsequences ($s_{n_k}$)$_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $s_{n_k}$ = t for all $k$. Such subsequences of ($s_n$) are boring monotonic sequences converging to $t.$

Henceforth, we assume { $n \in\mathbb{N} \space$ : $\space s_n = t$} is finite. Then

$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space $ {$ { n \in\mathbb{N} \space :0< |{s_n} - t| <\varepsilon}$} is infinite for all $\varepsilon>0$.

Since these sets equal

$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space $ {$n\in \mathbb{N} : t-\varepsilon < s_n < t$} $\cup$ {$n\in \mathbb{N} : t < s_n < t+ \varepsilon$},

and these sets get smaller as $\varepsilon \longrightarrow 0$, we have

$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space$ {$n\in \mathbb{N} : t-\varepsilon < s_n < t$} is infinite for all $\varepsilon > 0$,  $\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space $     (1)

or

$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space$ {$n\in \mathbb{N} : t < s_n < t+ \varepsilon$} is infinite for all $\varepsilon > 0$; $\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space $     (2)

otherwise, for sufficiently small $\varepsilon >0$, the sets in both (1) and (2) would be finite. We assume (1) holds, and leave the case that (2) holds to the reader. We will show how to define or construct step-by-step subsequence ($s_{n_k}$)$_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfying$\space$ $t-1 < s_{n_1} < t$ and

$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space $ max{$s_{n_{k-1}}, t- \frac{1}{k}$} $\leq s_{n_k} < t$ for $k \geq 2$. $\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  $ (3)

Specifically, we will assume $n_1, n_2, ... , n_{k-1}$ have been selected satisfying (3) and show how to select $n_k$. This will give us an infinite increasing sequence ($n_k$)$_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ and hence a subsequence ($s_{n_k}$) of ($s_n$) satisfying (3). SInce we will have $s_{n_{k-1}}$ $\leq$ $s_{n_k}$ for all $k$, this subsequence will be monotonically increasing. Since (3) also will imply $t - \frac{1}{k}$ $\leq$ $s_{n_k}$ $< t$ for all $k$, we will have lim$_ks_{n_k} = t$.

A construction like the one described aove, and executed below, is called an "inductive definition" or "definition by induction," even though the validity of the process is not a direct consequence of the Peano axiom that states "A subset of $\mathbb{N}$ which contanins $1$, and which contains $n + 1$ whenever it contains $n$, must equal $\mathbb{N}$."

Here is the construction. Select $n_1$ so that $t-1 < s_{n_1} < t $; this is possible by (1). Suppose $n_1, n_2, ..., n_{k-1}$ have been selected so that

$\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space n_1 < n_2 < \space ... \space < n_{k-1} \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  $ (4)

and

$ \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space$  max{$s_{n_{j-1}}, t- \frac{1}{j}$} $\leq s_{n_j} < t$ $\space \space $ for $\space \space $ $j = 2, \space ... \space , k-1$ $ \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space $ (5)

Using (1) with $\varepsilon$ = max{$s_{n_{k-1}}, t- \frac{1}{k}$}, we can select $n_k > n_{k-1}$ satisfying (5) for $j = k$, so that (3) holds for $k$. The procedure defines the sequence ($n_k$)$_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. This completes the proof. $\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  \space \Box$

To be honest I don't quite understand anything that is happening in this proof and the intuitive meaning behind what is happening. It appears to me that the theorem is saying that for any $\varepsilon >0$ and real number $t$ a sequence ($s_n$) will converge to that $t$ if and only if there exist an infinite number of $N$ such that $n > N$ implies |${s_n} - t$| <$\varepsilon$.

I'm assuming that my lack of understanding stems from a basic lack of understanding of limits and convergence in general and perhaps even an inability to visualize what this proof is saying. I appreciate any and all help in understanding this proof and I apologize for it's length!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind the proof is quite simple once you get rid of the useless verbosity.

You start by using the fact that $\{n: |u_n-t|<1\}$ is infinite, take $n_1$ in it.

Then you can use the fact that $\{n: |u_n-t|<\dfrac12\}$ is infinite, take $n_2$ in it strictly bigger than $n_1$.

Proceeding as this by induction, for each $k$ you can choose $n_k$ such that $|u_{n_k}-t|<\dfrac1k$ and $n_k>n_{k-1}>\dots>n_1$.

You have built a subsequence $u_{n_1},u_{n_2},\dots$ converging to $t$.

The intuition is that the assumption allows you to pick elements as close as you want to $t$, and as far as you want in the sequence, so it is all you need to build a subsequence converging to $t$.